# How to active button without click

Tags: vue.js

I want to active button when I access to my website

```html
<template>
  <div class="product-tab-list text-center mb-65 nav" role="tablist">
    <a href data-toggle="tab" role="tab" @click="sendDatatoApp()">
      <h4>{{ productsCategory[0].categories_name }}</h4>
    </a>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: Why not using this.$refs.button.click() in mounted() hook after applying a ref="button" field to your button? Why not just calling sendDatatoApp() function into you main component mounted() hook?

Comment: What it mean to active button? you can use created `created() { this.sendDatatoApp() }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to call this method sendDatatoApp() on application start, you can do this by calling this method in created or mounted hook.

```
mounted () {
  this.sendDatatoApp()
}
```

OR

```
created () {
  this.sendDatatoApp()
}
```